# Gaming Laptop with only Cooling Pad

Tags: laptop, gpu, fan, cooling

My 4 year old gaming laptop (15.6" Sager) started having GPU fan troubles a few weeks ago. It has now gotten to the point where the GPU fan is so loud I cannot use it without headphones. I have checked inside the chassis and the fan is not blocked by dust. I also tightened all of the screws holding the fan casing down and still no luck. I tried searching for a replacement fan but all the ones I have found are out of stock.

I just bought a 4-fan cooling pad that I really like so far. Could I get away with removing the GPU fan from the laptop and just have the cooling pad always be on? My instinct says no since it won't be blowing directly on the GPU, but I don't know what other options I have.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the fan and search for the model number on the fan itself, not by computer model. It will be available, or one that can be modified to fit.

The cooling pad may work, but if it doesn't then new laptop needed.

Answer (score 0):

What type of cooling pad do you have? is it a "Wal-Mart $20-25 cooling pad" or a "modern high-end GAMING laptop cooler"? Here's a useful [AnandTech Forum](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2301132) link that's a good point of reference. I would say trust your instinct first, notice how you or your your child positions the laptop second.  Make sure the laptop is under a flat cool surface like a desk an not on top of fabrics or clothing (avoid using it on the lap). Buy a high-end GAMING laptop cooler third (or make sure your's is), and if you do actually remove the GPU, I would be learn to be more knowledgeable of how to monitor the internal temps of your computer hardware in terms of the recommend temp settings and then monitor it's activity after removal.